# pg upgrade saving database definition taking time

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-8.4, pg-dump, pg-upgrade

I am in process of a pg_upgrade from 8.4 to 9.3. 
I am using this technique:

http://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/pg_upgrade.pdf

The upgrade has been running since 250 hours, and it has been on the step saving database definition since 160 hours. This is the current output of strace last few lines:

```
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|.             
POLLERR}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=5,   
revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(5, "T\0\0\0F
\0\2reltoastrelid\0\0\0\4\353\0\n
\0\0\0\32\0"..., 16384, 0, NULL, 
NULL) = 122
(5, "Q\0\0\0\221SELECT 
attname, attacl FROM"..., 146,  
MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 146
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|
POLLERR}], 1, -1
```

Is there a way to estimate how much time it will take? 
There are ~3,300,000 objects in pg_class and the database has around 765,000 tables. There are around 3-5 columns in most tables, and around 2,000,000 records in total.

Comment: From what I can see, `pg_upgrade` should be really fast. Despite having a lot of tables, you don't have a really huge data (2kk is not all that much nowadays).I think you should try dump/restore on a separate machine. Do you really have any system activity, like disk IO or CPU usage? Or does it look like there is something locked?

Comment: This extreme slowness with a large number of objects is a known problem, presumably fixed but only in most recent versions. See [pg_upgrade on high number tables database issues](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFj8pRAv_hr5BoPjogg_dD=D_iHjK3KJCA4DgMh+uZnVzBzn7w@mail.gmail.com) or [Pg_upgrade speed for many tables](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20121105200817.GA16323@momjian.us)

Comment: @DanielVérité `pg_upgrade` will be using 9.3's `pg_dump` though, so it should be on the current release. To the OP: You should see if you can connect to the socket it's using and take a look at `pg_stat_activity`. My suggestion though: http://www.postgresql.org/support/professional_support/ .

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. I have 32 processors in my server and the upgrade is using 100% of one of them. along with that it is using 30GB Ram

Comment: Reposted to http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/78649/7788

Comment: @user3455531 Out of interest, how long does a normal `pg_dump` of this database take?

Comment: @Craig: quoting Jeff Janes in the first thread: _Unfortunately the worst of those bottlenecks were in the server, so they
depend on what database you are upgrading from_. That makes it clear that using 9.3's `pg_dump` does not help with this specific problem, it will only on future upgrades.

Comment: i never did a pg_dump on this database