# What are "interesting tables" in pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4, pg-dump

I am in process of a `pg_dump`. Here is the log at the start:

```
pg_dump: reading schemas
pg_dump: reading user-defined functions
pg_dump: reading user-defined types
pg_dump: reading procedural languages
pg_dump: reading user-defined aggregate functions
pg_dump: reading user-defined operators
pg_dump: reading user-defined operator classes
pg_dump: reading user-defined operator families
pg_dump: reading user-defined conversions
pg_dump: reading user-defined tables
pg_dump: reading table inheritance information
pg_dump: reading rewrite rules
pg_dump: reading type casts
pg_dump: finding inheritance relationships
pg_dump: reading column info for interesting tables
pg_dump:...............
pg_dump:...............
pg_dump: reading column info for interesting tables
pg_dump:...............
```

What does

> reading column info for interesting tables

mean?

Does it not read this info for all tables? Also in my `pg_dump`, i have this executed twice. Why is this?

Comment: I think this just means "tables of interest to this dump operation". It's verbose mode output really intended for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message is issued in `verbose` mode of [`pg_dump`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/app-pgdump.html) prior to executing [`getTableAttrs` function](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL8_4_STABLE/src/bin/pg_dump/pg_dump.c#L4710). This function collects information bout all attributes (columns) of all dumpable tables, thus the message “… *for interesting tables*”.

Function `getTableAttrs` is being called from [here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL8_4_STABLE/src/bin/pg_dump/common.c#L210) (this *is* the place where message comes from), inside `getSchemaData` function, meaning data is being processed per-schema.

I suppose you have 2 schemas in your scope, therefore you see this message twice.

Comment: Thanks! also looking at strace of pg_dump, the saving database schema also does the same. so whats the difference? Also does the saving database schema only go through the "interesting tables"?

Comment: @user3455531, sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: okay. so looking at strace of pg_dump, i see its taking relnake from pg_class, then going through all its attributes in pg_attribute. So its similar to reading columns of interesting tables right?

Comment: @user3455531, right. Those are internal tables, part of [`System catalogs`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/catalogs.html).

Comment: understood. So in saving database definition, it is only storing schema of internal tables. Is there a way to know how many internal tables i have?

Comment: @user3455531, all tables, *including* internal ones, are stored inside those internal tables. Check the link from the previous comment.

Comment: hmm. was also looking for answer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242963/pg-upgrade-saving-database-definition-taking-time.   maybe you can help:)